# Android Studio: Scale ImageView Boundary to fit within Image

Tags: android, xml, imageview

I want to scale the borders to fit the image. In my file explorer, the image is small and has fit, But hasn't fit in android Studio

[image: This is my Image.]

If I scale the width and height to a specific value, the whole image shrinks:

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2o45.png)

Edit: I got it by changing the scaleX and scaleY

Comment: please remove empty space around your image. Please see if this website can help you https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.type=clipart&foreground.clipart=android&foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0.25&foreColor=rgba(96%2C%20125%2C%20139%2C%200)&backColor=rgb(68%2C%20138%2C%20255)&crop=0&backgroundShape=square&effects=none&name=ic_launcher

Answer (score 0):

the empty space around image exist in your image , so edit your image and make sure that you crop the image so it just contain what you want.